# Correct Method to use Server Sent Events

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I have a Spring Boot application that uses an `SseEmitter` to stream messages. The consumer is a web app that uses `EventSource.onMessage` to receive the events. This works well, except that there aren't always messages and Spring Boot sends an error 503 if there is 30 seconds of silence.

There are a number of ways to approach this but I'm not sure what is considered the best practice in handling such a situation.

1. Set `SseEmitter`'s timeout in the constructor to a duration exceeding the expected usage session of the app (e.g. 2 hours)
2. Handle `EventSource.onError` where status is 503, call `close()` and re-initialise a new `EventSource`. This produces lots of noise in both front and backend logs from the (expected) errors.
3. Inject artificial "heartbeat" messages on a scheduled basis from the backend so that there is never radio silence, then ignoring such events on the frontend.

I can't find any literature documenting automatic reconnection from the frontend or Spring configuration to prevent the 503 error classification. Please enlighten me if there are better options than the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out none of the options are really necessary. The 503 is a result of a missing `onTimeout()` handler in Spring's `SseEmitter`. If this is added, the endpoint call returns 20x and the `EventSource` automatically performs another call in an infinite loop and continues to stream events.

```java
SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
emitter.onTimeout(() -> emitter.complete()});
```

Bonus: the other aspect that needs to be handled is clients disappearing. This can be achieved by maintaining a list of active emitters and removing them when a failure occurs during message delivery. (This example assumes a broadcast scenario where all clients receive the same events.)

```java
List<SseEmitter> emitters = new ArrayList<>();

public SseEmitter init() {
  SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter ();
  emitter.onCompletion(() -> emitters.remove(emitter));
  emitter.onTimeout(() -> {
    emitter.complete();
    emitters.remove(emitter);
  });
  emitters.add(emitter);
  return emitter;
}

public void broadcast(SseEventBuilder event) {
  List<SseEmitter> failures = new ArrayList<>();
  emitters.forEach(emitter -> {
    try {
      emitter.send(event);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      emitter.completeWithError(ex);
      failures.add(emitter);
    }
  });
  if (!failures.isEmpty()) {
    emitters.removeAll(failures);
  }
}
```